# How can I import a function of Octave to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am running my code in Matlab. But I also want to call a function in octave. How should I import the `qp` function of Octave to Matlab?

Answer (score 3):

The Octave language is a superset of the Matlab language. If `qp` only made use of the Matlab language, then you could simply add it to your Matlab path and be done with it.

However, Octave's [`qp`](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/6ea9681bb225/scripts/optimization/qp.m) makes extensive use of Octave only language so you basically have to port the code yourself.  There are no tools for this, you have to convert the code from one language to another.   In addition, the actual solver is the function [`__qp__`](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/6ea9681bb225/libinterp/corefcn/__qp__.cc) which is written in C++ and uses liboctave.
Two easier alternatives than porting `qp` are:

- save the data from your Matlab session into a file `save foo.mat mydata`, call Octave to do the work and save the results `system ('octave --eval ''load ("foo.mat"); qp (...); save foo.mat  ...;'`, and read the file back `load foo.mat`.
- or the much simpler alternative, just use Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Octave syntaxt is not totally compatible with MATLAB. For example the preferred syntax for defining function in Octave is like this:

```
function ret =  f()
    %do something
endfunction
```

but MATLAB doesn't accept that syntax and there are other differences like differences in calling native codes and ... so it is not simple to convert each statement of octave library to matlab or convert `oct` c++ source to mex.
A straightforward way is that you should have an installation of Octave and run octave script from it then save the results to a mat file and in MATLAB load the file . You may use [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function to execute octave or run it from shell.

Answer (score -3):

so lets say you have 2 files in the same directory. `a.m` and `b.m` In the script `b.m` if you type `a` as a line of code everything in a.m will happen (variable assignments function definitions computations etc...)

Additionally you can use the `import` statement for adding things to your import list. as seen [here.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#buvhez_-4)

Comment: I have a feeling `import` doesn't work the way that you think.

Comment: Read what the purpose of `import` does on that documentation page.... very carefully. Does it align with your reasoning here? *Hint: The code in this question is most likely **not** object-oriented in design*.